# $.ajax and C# MVC Controller returns error or nothing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX JS functions which calls a C# MVC HttpPost Controller. This will return an object but for the purposes of debugging I am just trying to return a string.

JS AJAX code:

```
function UpdateBlogFilters(month, year) {

var url = "/HttpPost/GetBlogPostsPerMonth";

if (month != null && month != "" && year != null && year != "") {
    alert(month + " " + year);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { monthValue: month, yearValue: year },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Data " + data);
            var markup = "";
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
            console.log("Error: " + response);
        }
    });
    console.log("1");
}
console.log("2");
}
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetBlogPostsPerMonth(int monthValue, int yearValue)
    {
        .... the non-debug code
        return Json("test");
    }
```

This is returning an error, but the responseText and any error information is blank? I have verified that the controller is being called and it is reaching the return statement in the C# without error.

Any help?

Comment: Examine the request in the browser dev tools, what is it returning?

Comment: try this: return Json(new {test = "ok"});

Comment: According to Firefox 'response' which is returned in the error clause is not defined. In Firefox the console log of response.responseText is never reached, nor is success, instead it jumps to console.log("1"); @reptildarat trying that returns the same thing as before, it doesn't go in either success or failure and skips to console.log("1").

Comment: Why do you have a directory called /HttpPost?

Comment: We have one controller that deals with all HttpPosts across the website.

Comment: what is the output when you call the controller without ajax?

Comment: Same code worked on my side... [___Check the code here___](http://codeshare.io/ZrgrP)

Comment: try setting ajax dataType to "json"

Comment: Thi has been passed to someone else for a second pair of eyes to look at. I will be sure to post you the answer after. I am thinking it may be some other JS in the same file messing a variable up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your C# code to read something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBlogPostsPerMonth(int monthValue, int yearValue)
{
    .... the non-debug code
    return Json(new { result = "test" });
}
```

Ultimately, you want to pass an object into `Json()`.  You can pass an instance of a class, or an anonymous type, or dynamic.

Comment: Yes, this was also necessary for it to work. Return the object directly did not work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution. The AJAX call in itself worked fine. All code posted here was correct as per Bhavik.

The issue was that this AJAX request was called onclick of a hyperlink and this hyperlink although having no href set, was refreshing the page and somehow cancelling off the AJAX request. Removing the href to leave

```
<a onclick="UpdateBlogFilters(5,2014)">
```

resulted in the object being returned from AJAX successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have "/HttpPost/" in url?  Is that name of a controller that is different from the one you are using to render the view? Can you try without /HttpPost/

```
  var url = "GetBlogPostsPerMonth";
```

Comment: This ActionResult method was inside a file called HttpPostController.cs